# Ubuntu 19.10 notification (systray) area disappeared

Tags: gnome, 19.10, notification

Ok, when I upgraded from 19.04 to 19.10, I was forced into a login loop on gdm3. At the time I was not aware that the problem is related to autologin, so I just switched to lightdm and continued working.

Now, yesterday I finally got some time to solve this problem, and, as part of this attempt, I removed and reinstalled entire ubuntu gnome desktop (needlessly, as it was later revealed). Eventually I found the bug on issue tracker and removed auto login and reinstated gdm3 and I am now able to login.

However, I now no longer have any of my notification icons. Looks like the whole component is missing, so I presume I deleted some package which was not later reinstated. However, I am not familiar with the tech used, so I have no idea which packages and/or extensions to reinstall to get the notification area back. Any idea how to bring/enable this back?